# Resharper PSI Transaction newComment

Tags: c#, resharper

I've got an `ExecutePsiTransaction` Action containing

```
CSharpElementFactory factory =
    CSharpElementFactory.GetInstance(_highlighter.Declaration.GetPsiModule());
ICommentNode newComment = factory.CreateComment("// Not L10N");
ModificationUtil.AddChild(_highlighter.Declaration, newComment);
return null;
```

_highlighter is an `ICSharpLiteralExpression` and this works except it adds the comment right after the _highlighter instead of at the end of the line of code.  Any ideas are appreciated! Thank you!

I guess I'm looking for the way to find the line end of a `ICSharpLiteralExpression` as a `TreeNode` element?